# How WINS configuration in Windows and WebSphere MQ service account related

Tags: windows, dns, ibm-mq, fqdn

I have a question related to WINS configuration in Windows and how it affects the dcom config MQ domain service account used. My understanding is MQ is using **Domain\serviceaccount** for the dcom configuration in Windows and we cannot enter **FQDN\serviceaccount**

But when we removed WINS configuration in Windows 2008 server the Domain\serviceaccount in MQ dcom config is no longer recognized and we were getting error when trying to register MQ service with OS. As a workaround we had to add DNS suffices which enabled the MQ service to get registered to OS.

I wanted to know is this how it is supposed to work with DNS and no WINS configuration in a Windows OS? We are using MQ version 7.0.1.8 and is there any fixes in future releases where we can use **FQDN\serviceaccount** in dcom config for IBM MQSeries.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if it *solves* the problem, but 7.1 onwards no longer has a DCOM object anymore. The service itself is configured to run under the domain id from the PrepareWizard, look at the identities tab of the service.

Why can you not enter the FQDN\serviceaccount anyway, what breaks? If the prepare wizard doesnt let you do it, can you set it manually through the dcom MQSeries identity page (dcomcnfg, work downwards)?